# Flutter go_router how can i route previous path

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-go-router

I have a page in my app that shows a message saying 'Feature is implementing', and it has a back button to return to the same route the user was on before. I have tried using navigator.pop() and keeping the history, but neither of those solutions have worked. I have also tried adding an extra parameter to the route, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I am using GoRouter, and I have defined a route for the 'Feature is implementing' page like this:

router.dart

```
      GoRoute(
      path: '/coming-soon/:previousRoute',
      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
        final previousRoute = state.params['previousRoute'];
        return MaterialPage(
          key: ValueKey('coming-soon'),
          child: AppComingSoon(previousRoute: previousRoute),
        );
      },
    ),
```

And here is the code for the AppComingSoon widget:

```
class AppComingSoon extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? previousRoute;
  final String? extraData;

  const AppComingSoon({Key? key, this.previousRoute, this.extraData})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        titleSpacing: 4,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(PhosphorIcons.arrowLeft),
          onPressed: () {
            (context).go("/$previousRoute");
          },
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(context.l10n.buttonBack),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
            height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.55,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: Image.asset(
                  'assets/Graphics/coming-soon.png',
                ).image,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: getProportionateScreenWidth(16),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: getProportionateScreenWidth(20),
              right: getProportionateScreenWidth(20),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "implementing this feature in the app.",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.substitleSemiBold,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: getProportionateScreenWidth(16),
                ),
                Text(
                  "If you need support with this topic",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1Regular,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am calling the 'Feature is implementing' page from multiple places in my app, including this example code for the GoalsPageBodyGoals widget:

```
class GoalsPageBodyGoals extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> data;

  const GoalsPageBodyGoals({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      ...data,
      const SizedBox(height: 24),
      Column(
        key: const Key('goals_page_action_buttons'),
        children: [
          AppButtons.button(
              onPressed: () => context.go('/add-goal'),
              child: Text(context.l10n.goalsListPrimaryButtonText)),
          AppButtons.textButton(
            onPressed: () => context.go('/coming-soon/goals'),
            phosphorIcon: PhosphorIcons.arrowRight,
            child: Text(context.l10n.goalsListTextLink),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `context.pop();` to pop like we do on navigator1 `navigator.pop()`.

and navigator.push is like `context.push()` and `context.pushNamed()`.

Comment: So replace context.go with context.push and then you can use context.pop.

Comment: thanks but it was not working for me, then i did it like that


`
        GoRoute(
          name: 'coming-soon',
          path: '/coming-soon',
          builder: (context, _) {
            final data = _.extra as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return AppComingSoon(
              previousRoute: data['route']!,
              extraData: data['data'],
            );
          },
        ), `

Answer (score 0):

```
        GoRoute(
      name: 'coming-soon',
      path: '/coming-soon',
      builder: (context, _) {
        final data = _.extra as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return AppComingSoon(
          previousRoute: data['route']!,
          extraData: data['data'],
        );
      },
    ),
```

this solution worked for me

and in the back button

```
     onPressed: () {
        (context).go("$previousRoute", extra: extraData);
      },
    ),
```